# Display special characters in generated PDF from HTML content using wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to display special characters in a generated PDF file from HTML content and I'm using those special characters "\u2611" and "\u2610".

when the content converts to PDF file, they appear like "â˜‘".

the charset of my generated PDF is UTF-8.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding this line to the beginning of the html content:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```